# Comparing Symbols using Memoize function using Array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare two different `Symbol()` using memoize function. So far `id1 === id2 - true` should be `false`.  I see where is the problem but not sure how to fix it. Let me know if you have any ideas or how to fix it. No `Map` for this one

```
const obj = {};
let counter = 1;
function foo() {
  counter += 1;
  return counter;
}

function memoize(fn) {
  const cache = {};
  return (...args) => {
    const stringifiedArgs = JSON.stringify(
      args.map(arg => (typeof arg === 'symbol' ? arg.toString() : arg))
    );
    const result = (cache[stringifiedArgs] = !cache.hasOwnProperty(
      stringifiedArgs
    )
      ? fn(...args)
      : cache[stringifiedArgs]);
    return result;
  };
}

let id1 = Symbol('id');
let id2 = Symbol('id');

const memoizedFoo = memoize(foo);
console.log(memoizedFoo(id1)); // 2
console.log(memoizedFoo(id1)); // 2
console.log(memoizedFoo(id2)); // 2
console.log(memoizedFoo(id2)); // 2
```

**final- SOLUTION**
I am adding final solution while work pending is done. And all the test you can see at the bottom.

```
let counter = 1;
function foo() {
  counter += 1;
  return counter;
}

function symbolId(symbol) {
  let id = symbolId.list.indexOf(symbol);
  if (id < 0) id = symbolId.list.push(symbol) - 1; // push returns new length.
  return `\uF8FF${id}`; // F8FF is the last "private use" in the BMP.
}
symbolId.list = []; // Yes, it is possible to add things on a function.

function stringifyArgs(args) {
  return JSON.stringify(args, (key, value) => {
    const toStringVar = Object.prototype.toString.call(value);
    const objectTypes = [
      '[object Symbol]',
      '[object RegExp]',
      '[object Function]',
      '[object Object]'
    ];
    return objectTypes.includes(toStringVar) //if
      ? symbolId(value)
      : toStringVar === '[object Undefined]' //if
      ? String(value) //use String() for [object Undefined] - toString() Does not work
      : value;
  });
}

function memoize(fn) {
  const cache = {};
  return (...args) => {
    const stringifiedArgs = stringifyArgs(args);
    if (!(stringifiedArgs in cache)) {
      //!cache.hasOwnProperty(stringifiedArgs)
      cache[stringifiedArgs] = fn(...args);
    }
    return cache[stringifiedArgs];
  };
}



const id1 = Symbol('id');
const id2 = Symbol('id');
const re = new RegExp('ab+c');
const ex = new RegExp('ab+c');
const obj1 = { a: 1 };
const obj2 = { a: 1 };
let typeFnc1 = (a, b) => {
  let c = a + b;
};
let typeFnc2 = (c, d) => {
  let f = c + d;
};
let typeFnc3 = () => {};
let typeFnc4 = () => {};

const memoizedFoo = memoize(foo);
console.log(memoizedFoo(id1)); // 2
console.log(memoizedFoo(id1)); // 2
console.log(memoizedFoo(id2)); // 3
console.log(memoizedFoo(id2)); // 3
console.log(memoizedFoo(null)); // 4
console.log(memoizedFoo(null)); //4
console.log(memoizedFoo(undefined)); // 5
console.log(memoizedFoo(undefined)); //5
console.log(memoizedFoo(5)); // 6
console.log(memoizedFoo(5)); // 6
console.log(memoizedFoo(obj1)); // 7
console.log(memoizedFoo(obj1)); // 7
console.log(memoizedFoo(obj2)); // 8
console.log(memoizedFoo(obj2)); // 8
console.log(memoizedFoo(4)); // 9
console.log(memoizedFoo(3, 4, 5, 6)); //10
console.log(memoizedFoo(3, 4, 5, 6)); //10
console.log(memoizedFoo(3, 4, 6)); //11
console.log(memoizedFoo(3, 4, 6)); //11
console.log(memoizedFoo(typeFnc1)); // 12
console.log(memoizedFoo(typeFnc1)); //12
console.log(memoizedFoo(typeFnc2)); // 13
console.log(memoizedFoo(typeFnc2)); //13
console.log(memoizedFoo(typeFnc3)); // 14
console.log(memoizedFoo(typeFnc3)); //14
console.log(memoizedFoo(typeFnc4)); // 15
console.log(memoizedFoo(typeFnc4)); //15
console.log(memoizedFoo(re)); //16
console.log(memoizedFoo(re)); //16
console.log(memoizedFoo(ex)); //17
console.log(memoizedFoo(ex)); //17
console.log(memoizedFoo(id1, [id1, id2])); // 18
console.log(memoizedFoo(id1, [id1, id2])); // 18
```

Comment: what exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: What are you trying to do???? You create two symbols, then you convert them to strings (both with the same string value of `Symbol('id')`)...

Comment: @some I am trying to safe the argument of the function into the `cache` as the `key` and assign the result of the `foo` function as the value. if the function is called with the same argument it will not execute and display value from the `cache` .

Comment: You should look into [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of using an object.

Comment: @some I agree with you but I need to implement it without Map. I will do it after this one.

Comment: @fila90 whenever I call the function with the different argument it should increment.

Comment: You should use the replacer-function of the stringify-function, so that you handle if you get a symbol in an array `const stringifiedArgs = JSON.stringify( args, (key, value) => typeof value === 'symbol' ? value.toString() : value);`

Comment: Your main problem is that you convert your unique symbols to strings, and when you do that, you get their optional descriptions instead, and since you have the same descriptions they are the same after you have stringified them. Symbols should not be stringified, and if you do it anyway, and want to know if they are different, you need to store a unique identifier for each symbol, for example with a  WeakMap.

Comment: @some very valid point but I need to use `array` for this one. this is just for educational purpose. We actually need two implementation `array` and `WeakMap` + `Map`

Comment: I tried WeakMap, but it needs an object as a key, and symbols are primitive values. So a Map or Array should be used instead. I did part of it in my answer (too much to write in a comment)

Comment: Please do not edit your original question. Just post an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you convert your unique symbols to strings, and when you do that, you get their optional descriptions instead, and since you have the same descriptions they are the same after you have stringified them. Symbols should not be stringified, and if you do it anyway, and want to know if they are different, you need to store a unique identifier for each symbol.

Quick and very dirty function that stores each symbol in an array, and returns an unique identifier as a string.

```
function symbolId(symbol) {
  let id = symbolId.list.indexOf(symbol);
  if (id < 0) id = symbolId.list.push(symbol) - 1; // push returns new length.
  return `\uF8FF${id}`; // F8FF is the last "private use" in the BMP. 
}
symbolId.list = []; // Yes, it is possible to add things on a function.
```

And then I replaced your conversion like this:

```
const stringifiedArgs = JSON.stringify(
  args,
  (key, value) => typeof value === 'symbol' ? symbolId(value) : value
);
```

Complete example (with updates from your final solution)

```js
function foo() {
  return foo.counter += 1;
}
foo.counter = 0;

function symbolId(symbol) {
  let id = symbolId.list.indexOf(symbol);
  if (id < 0) id = symbolId.list.push(symbol) - 1; // push returns new length.
  return `\uF8FF${id}`; // F8FF is the last "private use" in the BMP.
}
symbolId.list = []; // Yes, it is possible to add things on a function.

function memoize(fn) {
  const cache = {};
  return (...args) => {
    const stringifiedArgs = JSON.stringify(args, (key, value) =>
      {
        const toString = Object.prototype.toString.call(value); // Cache toString result
        return (
          toString === '[object Symbol]' ||
          toString === '[object RegExp]' ||
          toString === '[object Function]' ||
          toString === '[object Object]'
          ) ? symbolId(value)
            : toString === '[object Undefined]'
            ? String(value)
            : value
      }
    );
    const result = (cache[stringifiedArgs] = !cache.hasOwnProperty(
      stringifiedArgs
    )
      ? fn(...args)
      : cache[stringifiedArgs]);
    return result;
  };
}
// creating a memoized function for the 'add' pure function
const id1 = Symbol('id');
const id2 = Symbol('id');
const re = new RegExp('ab+c');
const ex = new RegExp('ab+c');
const obj1 = { a: 1 };
const obj2 = { a: 1 };
let typeFnc1 = (a, b) => {
  let c = a + b;
};
let typeFnc2 = (c, d) => {
  let f = c + d;
};
let typeFnc3 = () => {};
let typeFnc4 = () => {};


function test(result, expected) {
  console.log('%s: %s ', result === expected, result );
}
const memoizedFoo = memoize(foo);
test(memoizedFoo(id1),1);
test(memoizedFoo(id1),1);
test(memoizedFoo(id2),2);
test(memoizedFoo(id2),2);
test(memoizedFoo(null),3);
test(memoizedFoo(null),3);
test(memoizedFoo(undefined),4);
test(memoizedFoo(undefined),4);
test(memoizedFoo(5),5);
test(memoizedFoo(5),5);
test(memoizedFoo(obj1),6);
test(memoizedFoo(obj1),6);
test(memoizedFoo(obj2),7);
test(memoizedFoo(obj2),7);
test(memoizedFoo(4),8);
test(memoizedFoo(3, 4, 5, 6),9);
test(memoizedFoo(3, 4, 5, 6),9);
test(memoizedFoo(3, 4, 6),10);
test(memoizedFoo(3, 4, 6),10);
test(memoizedFoo(typeFnc1),11);
test(memoizedFoo(typeFnc1),11);
test(memoizedFoo(typeFnc2),12);
test(memoizedFoo(typeFnc2),12);
test(memoizedFoo(typeFnc3),13);
test(memoizedFoo(typeFnc3),13);
test(memoizedFoo(typeFnc4),14);
test(memoizedFoo(typeFnc4),14);
test(memoizedFoo(re),15);
test(memoizedFoo(re),15);
test(memoizedFoo(ex),16);
test(memoizedFoo(ex),16);
test(memoizedFoo(id1, [id1, id2]),17);
test(memoizedFoo(id1, [id1, id2]),17);
```

Comment: it works! I am trying to integrate it with `[object Function]`, `[object Undefined]`, `[object Null]` , `[object RegExp]` , `[object Object]`, `[object Array]`

Comment: undefined and null is easy, since every undefined is exactly the same and every null i exactly the same. You can use the same symbolId function for Function, RegExp, and Object (JSONstringify should take care if Array)

Comment: I wounder if converting to string really is the way you are supposed to solve this.

Comment: I updated my initial question with the intermediary solution

Comment: this one is done. just completed all the test successfully. I will try to do another one with `WeakMap` + `Map`. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I updated my answer, with your new solution, but with some tweaks, for example caching the value of toString.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**
This is the final solution that I woked out with @some . It takes into account different types of arguments:`[object Array],[object Object],[object Function],[object Symbol],    [object Undefined], [object Null], [object RegExp]`

```
let counter = 1;
function foo() {
  counter += 1;
  return counter;
}

function symbolId(symbol) {
  let id = symbolId.list.indexOf(symbol);
  if (id < 0) id = symbolId.list.push(symbol) - 1; // push returns new length.
  return `\uF8FF${id}`; // F8FF is the last "private use" in the BMP.
}
symbolId.list = []; // Yes, it is possible to add things on a function.

 function stringifyArgs(args) {
  const replacer = (key, value) => {
    const toStringVar = Object.prototype.toString.call(value);
    const objectTypes = [
      '[object Symbol]',
      '[object RegExp]',
      '[object Function]',
      '[object Object]'
    ];
    return objectTypes.includes(toStringVar) //if
      ? symbolId(value)
      : toStringVar === '[object Undefined]' //if
      ? String(value) //use String() for [object Undefined] - toString() Does not work
      : value;
  };

  return JSON.stringify(args, replacer);
}

function memoize(fn) {
  const cache = {};
  return (...args) => {
    const stringifiedArgs = stringifyArgs(args);
    if (!(stringifiedArgs in cache)) {
      //!cache.hasOwnProperty(stringifiedArgs)
      cache[stringifiedArgs] = fn(...args);
    }
    return cache[stringifiedArgs];
  };
}


const id1 = Symbol('id');
const id2 = Symbol('id');
const re = new RegExp('ab+c');
const ex = new RegExp('ab+c');
const obj1 = { a: 1 };
const obj2 = { a: 1 };
let typeFnc1 = (a, b) => {
  let c = a + b;
};
let typeFnc2 = (c, d) => {
  let f = c + d;
};
let typeFnc3 = () => {};
let typeFnc4 = () => {};

const memoizedFoo = memoize(foo);
console.log(memoizedFoo(id1)); // 2
console.log(memoizedFoo(id1)); // 2
console.log(memoizedFoo(id2)); // 3
console.log(memoizedFoo(id2)); // 3
console.log(memoizedFoo(null)); // 4
console.log(memoizedFoo(null)); //4
console.log(memoizedFoo(undefined)); // 5
console.log(memoizedFoo(undefined)); //5
console.log(memoizedFoo(5)); // 6
console.log(memoizedFoo(5)); // 6
console.log(memoizedFoo(obj1)); // 7
console.log(memoizedFoo(obj1)); // 7
console.log(memoizedFoo(obj2)); // 8
console.log(memoizedFoo(obj2)); // 8
console.log(memoizedFoo(4)); // 9
console.log(memoizedFoo(3, 4, 5, 6)); //10
console.log(memoizedFoo(3, 4, 5, 6)); //10
console.log(memoizedFoo(3, 4, 6)); //11
console.log(memoizedFoo(3, 4, 6)); //11
console.log(memoizedFoo(typeFnc1)); // 12
console.log(memoizedFoo(typeFnc1)); //12
console.log(memoizedFoo(typeFnc2)); // 13
console.log(memoizedFoo(typeFnc2)); //13
console.log(memoizedFoo(typeFnc3)); // 14
console.log(memoizedFoo(typeFnc3)); //14
console.log(memoizedFoo(typeFnc4)); // 15
console.log(memoizedFoo(typeFnc4)); //15
console.log(memoizedFoo(re)); //16
console.log(memoizedFoo(re)); //16
console.log(memoizedFoo(ex)); //17
console.log(memoizedFoo(ex)); //17
console.log(memoizedFoo(id1, [id1, id2])); // 18
console.log(memoizedFoo(id1, [id1, id2])); // 18
```